# How to stop back navigation to login page

Tags: java, android

I have a login form and a button which when click starts another activity. But after pressing the back button on the bottom left of the phone, it navigates back to the login activity. How can I prevent this. This is what I've been working with :-

```java
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));    
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just close the activity that you no longer need using finish()

```
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
    finish();
   }
});
```

Comment: it does stop back navigation. When back button is pressed, the app minimizes and then when the ap is restored. It again opens a the login page. How to prevent that ?

Comment: That is the expected behaviour of back button on an Android device as it destroys the activity, you can look for how to override back button, but I would suggest, saving logged state of a user and check it once the app is launched, if he is logged, straight away start home activity and pass his details if needed

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. See the example bellow:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class)); 
finish ();//try this